# Instructables "Omnibot" -- using the "real" Uno R3 board

Tags: arduino-uno

Step 4 of this instructable uses what seems to be a "knock-off" development version of the Uno R3 board, where an RF receiver is soldered to pads that don't exist on the R3 or R3 SMD boards:

https://www.instructables.com/OmniBot-Easy-Arduino-RC-Robots/

> ...
>
> 4. Locate available Gnd, Vcc, and Rx holes on your Arduino. (if using the recommended Arduino they can be found all near each other just below the ICSP pins.)
> 5. Insert the tinned wires through their respective holes and solder on the back side. White to RX, red to 5V, black to GND.
>
> ...

I am completely new to Arduino, so I'm a little puzzled by the lack of VCC. Sounds like this is just power. Is there any reason I can't hook the RF receiver to the D0 (RX) pin, 5v out, and GND headers?

Comment: `Vcc` is positive voltage supply ... 5 V

Comment: your question becomes useless when the instructables link dies ... please add the necessary diagrams to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the holes they are showing it connected to are physically connected to the pins you mention.  Connecting directly to those pins would be equivalent.